# Fusion Table with App Inventor: displaying map with location column

Tags: dictionary, geolocation, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I am using App Inventor 2 from MIT.

I have a fusion table with location column of type location. Using the `FusiontableControls` component I am able to write into the table and view the table using the `WebViewer` component, I am able to view the URL of the Table and the data is there.

However, when I use the URL from the Map view of the table, I see the map display on my app but without the locations in the table marked. However, if I go to the web address of the fusion table on a web browser on a pc, hit the location button, the map updates with the location information and next time I use the app, the map shows with the locations marked.

Is there a way to display the updated map using App Inventor without having to go manually and update the map page?

**Update 1**: As @Taifun suggested, I tried `clear cache`. It doesn't work.

**Update 2**: Further investigations show that by default, location info in FusionTable is not geocoded and that is why map doesn't show it. The question now is whether there is an API that forces geocoding when I insert the location info into the fusion table using app inventor 2?

[image]

**Update 3**: Taifun's suggestion worked. Storing address as lat,long makes the map automatically geocode and display locations. Earlier I was using the address returned from location sensor which returns something like 123 Main St, city,st 12345. Even though it is a valid address, it doesn't auto geocode.

Thanks a lot Taifun. (also for editing my post for clarity)

Comment: probably a cache problem?
first use the `Webviewer.ClearCache` block and then display the url again

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Here is the snippet of coe

Comment: you might want to edit your question and add a screenshot of your relevant blocks (not only the blocks of my suggestion). As Stackoverflow beginner, you do not have permission to add a screenshot, but you can link to an image at for example [imgur.com](http://imgur.com)...

Comment: can you share your project code?

Comment: Hi Taifun, Mike: 
Thanks for the help. I could not cut and paste code but here is a link: http://imgur.com/xZFTaab
Further investigations show that by default, location info in FusionTable is not geocoded and that is why map doesn't show it. The question now is whether there is an API that forces geocoding when I insert the location info into the fusion table  using app inventor 2?

Comment: I updated your question for you, see also [How does editing work](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)...

Comment: Great, it works four you! Also you found out, how to edit your question. What you still need to find out is, [how to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)... Thank you.

Comment: I accepted it. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your location as **one column location** like this
[image]
[image]

instead of using two separate columns (lat and long) in your table. This should update your map automatically. See also https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1012281?hl=en